# Are traffic statistics and analytics broken for Parenting?

Tags: bug, site-evaluation

On a whim today I decided to look at the [site analytics for Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/).  Most things appeared to be about where I thought they would (new questions, answers, votes, etc.).  But the traffic analytics don't look correct.  For a long period of time they show that the site has no traffic at all (obviously untrue, as I know I've been visiting, and the presence of new posts and votes had to come from somewhere).  Then there is a large spike for a week or two then it peters back down to nothing.

Also, looking at the traffic sources shows nothing (including some NaN errors, probably divide by zero errors).  So am I just crazy or am I misunderstanding how something works or is it really broken?  And if it is broken, how do we report this so it can get addressed?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Do you experience something like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/377968)?

Comment: @AnneDaunted Kinda, what I'm seeing is more like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309229/).

Comment: It looks like it. Every beta site’s views per day are all messed up. I believe the issue has been raised on Meta.SE.

Comment: I added a link (for those that don't know how to get to site analytics) and a pic (for those who can't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you and Anne noted in comments, this seems to be SE-wide.  [This Meta.SE quetion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51/) includes this bit from a developer in the answers:

> We're investigating, we've had a number of large changes to our Google Analytics infrastructure, looks like we missed some bits...